# How to solve " [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module" for Webpack case?

Tags: node.js, webpack, esmodules

I tried to import the [w3c-html-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/w3c-html-validator) but got the error

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module D:(...)\node_m
> odules\w3c-html-validator\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js from
> D:(...)\node_modules\w3c-html-validator\dist\w3c-html-validator.umd.cjs
> not supported.

Looks like this problem is with [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk), the dependency of **w3c-html-validator**.

I am using the Webpack with [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals).
Thank to it, `export`/`import` keywords are available even though the output is the CommonJS and indented to be executed by plain Node.js. It should be the specific solution for this case, not just "add `type: module` to your `package.json`".

If possible, I want to avoid the adding of `type: module` to the **package.json** because it could cause other errors. Currently, I have about 30 dependencies (see the appendix) and neither of them requires `type: module`.

### Appendix

#### Webpack setup

```js
import Webpack from "webpack";
import Path from "path";

import NodeExternalsPlugin from "webpack-node-externals";
import ForkTypeScriptCheckerWebpackPlugin from "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin";
import ESLintPlugin from "eslint-webpack-plugin";

import type { ArbitraryObject } from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions";


export default function generateConfiguration(
  _environment: ArbitraryObject, commandArguments: ArbitraryObject
): Webpack.Configuration {

  const SOURCE_CODE_ROOT_DIRECTORY_ABSOLUTE_PATH: string = Path.resolve(__dirname, "Source");

  const __IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__: boolean = commandArguments.mode === "development";
  const __IS_PRODUCTION_BUILDING_MODE__: boolean = commandArguments.mode === "production";

  return {

    target: "node",

    context: SOURCE_CODE_ROOT_DIRECTORY_ABSOLUTE_PATH,
    entry: { EntryPoint: "./EntryPoint.ts" },

    output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: "[name].js",
      library: {
        type: "commonjs"
      }
    },

    /* [ Theory ] Valid non-undefined values are only "development", "production" and "none". */
    mode: __IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__ ? "development" : "production",
    watch: __IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__,
    optimization: {
      emitOnErrors: __IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__,
      minimize: __IS_PRODUCTION_BUILDING_MODE__
    },

    node: {
      __dirname: false
    },

    devtool: false,

    externals: [
      NodeExternalsPlugin({
        allowlist: [ "rev-hash" ]
      })
    ],

    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/u,
          loader: "ts-loader",
          options: {
            /* [ Theory ] 'ForkTypeScriptCheckerWebpackPlugin' will execute the type checking. */
            transpileOnly: true
          }
        }
      ]
    },

    resolve: {
      extensions: [ ".ts", ".js" ],
      alias: { /* ... */ }
    },

    plugins: [
      new Webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__,
        __IS_PRODUCTION_BUILDING_MODE__
      }),
      new ForkTypeScriptCheckerWebpackPlugin({
        typescript: {
          /* [ Theory ] The default value is 'context', but the 'tsconfig.json' is 1 level above 'context'. */
          configFile: Path.resolve(__dirname, "tsconfig.json")
        }
      }),
      new ESLintPlugin({
        extensions: [ "js", "ts" ],
        failOnWarning: __IS_PRODUCTION_BUILDING_MODE__
      })
    ]
  };
}
```

#### Current dependencies

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.57.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.57.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "3.2.47",
    "@webdiscus/pug-loader": "2.10.4",
    "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions": 1.6.9,
    "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions-nodejs": "1.6.0-alpha.9",
    "@yamato-daiwa/style_guides": "0.0.47",
    "access-sniff": "3.2.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "browser-sync": "2.27.11",
    "cheerio": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "css-loader": "6.7.3",
    "cssnano": "5.1.14",
    "eslint": "8.37.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "11.1.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "7.3.0",
    "glob": "7.2.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-data": "1.3.1",
    "gulp-debug": "4.0.0",
    "gulp-html-prettify": "0.0.1",
    "gulp-if": "3.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "7.1.0",
    "gulp-intercept": "0.1.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "1.2.1",
    "gulp-postcss": "9.0.1",
    "gulp-pug": "5.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "3.0.0",
    "gulp-stylus": "2.7.1",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "9.0.2",
    "json5-loader": "4.0.1",
    "minimatch": "5.1.1",
    "node-notifier": "10.0.1",
    "prettier": "2.8.7",
    "pug-lint": "2.6.0",
    "pug-plain-loader": "1.1.0",
    "rev-hash": "4.0.0",
    "stlint": "1.0.65",
    "stream-combiner2": "1.1.1",
    "style-loader": "3.3.1",
    "stylus-loader": "7.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "9.4.2",
    "vinyl": "2.2.1",
    "vue": "3.2.47",
    "vue-loader": "17.0.1",
    "vue-style-loader": "4.1.3",
    "vue-tsc": "1.2.0",
    "w3c-html-validator": "1.3.3",
    "webpack": "5.76.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "3.0.0",
    "webpack-stream": "7.0.0",
    "worker-loader": "3.0.8",
    "yaml-loader": "0.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/browser-sync": "2.26.3",
    "@types/cheerio": "0.22.31",
    "@types/cssnano": "5.0.0",
    "@types/glob": "7.2.0",
    "@types/gulp": "4.0.10",
    "@types/gulp-debug": "2.0.32",
    "@types/gulp-html-prettify": "0.0.2",
    "@types/gulp-if": "0.0.34",
    "@types/gulp-imagemin": "8.0.1",
    "@types/gulp-intercept": "0.1.1",
    "@types/gulp-plumber": "0.0.33",
    "@types/gulp-postcss": "8.0.2",
    "@types/gulp-sourcemaps": "0.0.35",
    "@types/gulp-stylus": "2.7.4",
    "@types/node": "18.13.0",
    "@types/node-notifier": "8.0.2",
    "@types/pug": "2.0.6",
    "@types/webpack-node-externals": "2.5.3",
    "@types/webpack-stream": "3.2.12",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.3",
    "webpack-cli": "5.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why using webpack with the webpack-node-externals plugin? This plugin prevents all `node_modules` from being bundled together with your source code, which seems to be the source of your issue.

Comment: @VonC Because the bundling of Node.js dependencies could cause a many warnings. The usage of webpack-node-external is the recommended approach.

Comment: Have you tried just defining externals without `webpack-node-externals`?

Comment: @Slbox defining externals without `webpack-node-externals`? Would you please to share the link with example?

Comment: Try using a different version that doesn’t rely on chalk which is pure esm since v 5. Pick your dependencies better or understand how to work with esm/cjs boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the problem is that `w3c-html-validator` is using an ESM version of `chalk`. Basically, the maintainer of `w3c-html-validator` has built the UMD/CJS variant incorrectly by trying to `require` one of its own ESM dependencies .

**Simple solution**: Downgrade your version of `w3c-html-validator` to [`v0.8.1`](https://github.com/center-key/w3c-html-validator/blob/v0.8.1/package.json#L76) which uses a CommonJS version of `chalk`.

**Babel solution**: Add `babel-loader` to your webpack build and transpile the `chalk` dependency to convert the `import/export` to `require/module.exports`, i.e. ESM to CJS.

Your babel config should look something like this (add `@babel/preset-env` if not already in your devDependencies):

```json
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "modules": "commonjs"
    }]
  ]
}
```

Your updated webpack config should include something like this:

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(t|j)sx?$/,
      include: filename => {
        return /node_modules\/chalk/.test(filename)
      },
      use: ['babel-loader']
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is your use of `webpack-node-externals` you might have luck with code like below.

Note that this solution relies on you knowing which modules are native dependencies (which should not take long to figure out.)

You might update the beginning of your config like this:

```js
return {
    target: "node",
    externals: ['sharp', 'another-native-node-dep'], // Add your native dependency names to the array and remove my examples
    context: SOURCE_CODE_ROOT_DIRECTORY_ABSOLUTE_PATH,
    entry: { EntryPoint: "./EntryPoint.ts" },
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, the stopping of the usage of `webpack-node-externals` caused the another error, the `"development" = 'development' SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. It refers to the code automatically generated by Webpack. It looks like it is impossible to simply stop use the "webpack-node-externals", because basically it works fine.